# cancelAuthenticationChallenge fails with NSRangeException after user hits No

Tags: ios, nsurlconnection, uialertview, nsrangeexception

I am trying to cancel an NSURLAuthenticationChanllenge if the server certificate cannot be validated (in my case a self-signed), by popping up an UIAlertView with two buttons -- 'No' and 'Yes'

when user hits Yes, I proceed anyway, but when user hits No, I cancel it. This is how i am doing it. I am using the delegate for the UIAlertView to capture the index of the button that was clicked by the user. When I click Yes, it works fine, but when you click on No, I get an NSRangeException

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge {

if ([challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod isEqualToString:NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust])
{
    BOOL trusted;
    //Evaluate the cert here -- removed code to be brief

    if(trusted){
        NSURLCredential *credential = [NSURLCredential credentialForTrust:challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust];
        [challenge.sender useCredential:credential forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
    }else{
        //define a block
        self.certProceedBlock = ^(NSInteger clickedButton) {
            if(clickedButton == 1){
                NSURLCredential *credential = [NSURLCredential credentialForTrust:challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust];
                [challenge.sender useCredential:credential forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
            }else if(clickedButton == 0){
                [challenge.sender cancelAuthenticationChallenge:challenge]; //this fails with NSRangeException
            }
        };


        //pop up the Notification
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Unknown Certificate"
                                                        message:[NSString stringWithFormat:message, certificateSubjectName]
                                                       delegate:self
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"No"
                                              otherButtonTitles:@"Yes", nil];
        [alert show];


    }
}
```

}

Here is the delegate

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
if(self.certProceedBlock){
    self.certProceedBlock(buttonIndex);
}
```

}

The error is:
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'

As requested-- here is the full stackTrace

i tried to add the image of the stack trace -- but the image is too small.
here is the text. please copy into textEdit-- it should be better

[**NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x004e5946 __exceptionPreprocess + 182
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x02bd2a97 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x003c8bd2 -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:] + 210
    3   MYCODE**                 0x0017d9e1 -[HttpUtils getAuthTokenExpiration:] + 145
    4   MYCODE**                 0x0017dfb3 -[HttpUtils saveAuthTokenExpirationDate:] + 99
    5   MYCODE**                 0x0017ed5a __68-[HttpUtils getToken:params:username:password:tokenCompletionBlock:]_block_invoke + 218
    6   MYCODE**                 0x001850ce -[HttpUtils connection:didFailWithError:] + 334
    7   CFNetwork                           0x0497d38e __67-[NSURLConnectionInternalConnection cancelAuthenticationChallenge:]_block_invoke + 51
    8   CFNetwork                           0x04995879 __65-[NSURLConnectionInternal _withConnectionAndDelegate:onlyActive:]_block_invoke + 83
    9   CFNetwork                           0x0497cdd9 -[NSURLConnectionInternalConnection invokeForDelegate:] + 145
    10  CFNetwork                           0x04995813 -[NSURLConnectionInternal _withConnectionAndDelegate:onlyActive:] + 189
    11  CFNetwork                           0x04995a10 -[NSURLConnectionInternal _withConnectionAndDelegate:] + 58
    12  CFNetwork                           0x0497d314 -[NSURLConnectionInternalConnection cancelAuthenticationChallenge:] + 384
    13  CFNetwork                           0x048c100d -[NSURLConnection(NSURLAuthenticationChallengeSender) cancelAuthenticationChallenge:] + 50
    14  MYCODE**                 0x00184b82 __58-[HttpUtils connection:didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:]_block_invoke + 370
    15  MYCODE**                 0x00184f52 -[HttpUtils alertView:clickedButtonAtIndex:] + 178
    16  UIKit                               0x0186960d -[UIAlertView _prepareToDismissForTappedIndex:] + 192
    17  UIKit                               0x01868fa9 __35-[UIAlertView _prepareAlertActions]_block_invoke50 + 56
    18  UIKit                               0x018618b5 -[UIAlertController _dismissAnimated:triggeringAction:triggeredByPopoverDimmingView:] + 72
    19  UIKit                               0x01861868 -[UIAlertController _dismissAnimated:triggeringAction:] + 56
    20  UIKit                               0x01861454 -[UIAlertController _actionViewTapped:] + 68
    21  libobjc.A.dylib                     0x02be8771 -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:] + 70
    22  UIKit                               0x01a4474c -[_UIAlertControllerActionView _triggerSelect] + 60
    23  UIKit                               0x01a44607 -[_UIAlertControllerActionView touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 187
    24  UIKit                               0x019e47b7 _UIGestureRecognizerUpdate + 13225
    25  UIKit                               0x015fb26b -[UIWindow _sendGesturesForEvent:] + 1356
    26  UIKit                               0x015fc0cf -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 769
    27  UIKit                               0x015c1549 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 242
    28  UIKit                               0x015d137e _UIApplicationHandleEventFromQueueEvent + 20690
    29  UIKit                               0x015a5b19 _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 2206
    30  CoreFoundation                      0x004091df __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION** + 15
    31  CoreFoundation                      0x003feced __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 253
    32  CoreFoundation                      0x003fe248 __CFRunLoopRun + 952
    33  CoreFoundation                      0x003fdbcb CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 443
    34  CoreFoundation                      0x003fd9fb CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    35  GraphicsServices                    0x0697324f GSEventRunModal + 192
    36  GraphicsServices                    0x0697308c GSEventRun + 104
    37  UIKit                               0x015a98b6 UIApplicationMain + 1526
    38  MYCODE**                 0x001f857d main + 141
    39  libdyld.dylib                       0x03349ac9 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

** removed my app name and replaced with string MYCODE

Comment: Please add the full stack trace.

Comment: Hi Wain, i have added the stack trace. please take a look

Comment: Folks, my bad. I found why this is happening. after the user hits No, and authenticationChallenge is cancelled, another delegate with name ConnectionDidFailWithError:error is called.  Inside that delegate, I am doing stuff that is causing this NSRangeException. I took care of this in that delegate and everything is fine...sorry for the noise...and looking at the stack trace carefully did help me figure this out